# Creating Listbox subitems

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a listbox that needs to be divided into three predefined subitems. I want the listbox to scroll like the app listing on Windows Phone. (The letters, subitems, stick on the top). Any default controls that allow this kind of behavior?

Comment: Did you mean LongListSelector control ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Longlistselector for your purpose in that you have to groupby the observable collection to get the data as per grouping and bind it you can take reference from this demo
[grouped list in LongListSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

See the [Long list selector](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/05/23/windows-phone-8-xaml-longlistselector.aspx) as documented here

And a sample app [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/PeopleHub-Windows-Phone-80-88abe94d)